# Efficient algorithm for finding the largest overlapping range given a list of ranges

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, dynamic-programming

Consider the following interface that describes a continuous range of `integer` values.

```cs
public interface IRange {
    int Minimum { get;}
    int Maximum { get;}

    IRange LargestOverlapRange(IEnumerable<IRange> ranges);
}
```

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to find the largest overlap range given a list of `IRange` objects. The idea is briefly outlined in the following diagram. Where the top numbers represent the `integer` values, and the `|-----|` represent the `IRange` objects with a min and max value. I stacked the `IRange` objects so that the solution is easy to visualize.

```
0123456789  ...                            N
|-------|   |------------|        |-----|
   |---------|    |---|
       |---|             |------------|
               |--------|  |---------------|
                              |----------|
```

Here, the `LargestOverlapRange` method would return:

```
                                  |---|
```

Since that range has a total of 4 'overlaps'. If there are two separate `IRange` with the same number of overlaps, I want to return `null`.

Here is some brief code of what I tried.

```cs
public class Range : IRange 
{

    public IRange LargestOverlapRange(IEnumerable<IRange> ranges) {           

        int maxInt = 20000;    

        // Create a histogram of the counts
        int[] histogram = new int[maxInt];
        foreach(IRange range in ranges) {
            for(int i=range.Minimum; i <= range.Maximum; i++) {
                histogram[i]++;
            }
        }

        // Find the mode of the histogram
        int mode = 0;
        int bin = 0;
        for(int i =0; i < maxInt; i++) {
            if(histogram[i] > mode) {
                mode = histogram[i];
                bin = i;
            }
        }

        // Construct a new range of the mode values, if they are continuous
        Range range;
        for(int i = bin; i < maxInt; i++) {
            if(histogram[i] == mode) {  
                if(range != null)
                    return null; // violates two ranges with the same mode   
                range = new Range();             
                range.Minimum = i;                     
                while(i < maxInt && histrogram[i] == mode)
                    i++;
                range.Maximum = i;                    
            }
        }

        return range;
    }

}
```

This involves four loops and is easily O(n^2) if not higher. Is there a more efficient algorithm (speed wise) to find the largest overlap range from a list of other ranges?

**EDIT**

Yes, the O(n^2) is not correct, I was thinking about it incorrectly. It should be O(N * M) as was pointed out in the comments.

**EDIT 2**

Let me stipulate a few things, the absolute min and max values of the `integer` values will be from (0, 20000). Secondly, the average number of `IRange` will be on the order of 100. I don't know if this will change the way the algorithm is designed.

**EDIT 3**

I am implementing this algorithm on a scientific instrument (a mass spectrometer) in which the speed of the data processing is paramount to the quality of data (faster analysis time = more spectra collected in time T). The firmware language (proprietary) only has arrays[] and is not object orientated. I choose C# since I am decent at porting concepts between the two languages and thought that in the interest of the SO community, a good answer would have a wider audience.

Comment: IIRC you can do this with a double loop of the type: `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) for(var j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++) max = Math.max(max, GetOverlap(array[i], array[j]));`

Comment: This is not O(N^2); it is O(N * M) where N is the number of ranges and M is the maximum value in the domain. I cannot think of anything better myself, but some smart cookies have worked on algorithms like this for many decades. Do a web search.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'largest overlapping range'. Please could you give more examples? Say the ranges were 1 to 5, 2 to 6, 4 to 10 and 15 to 20.

Comment: @ColonelPanic the return value would be a range 4 to 5. The ints 4 and 5 appear in three of the four given ranges. They are also continuous, and no other continuous range shares the same mode (3). Think of the ranges as pieces of paper with a defined width and starting point. If you stacked all the pieces of paper on top of each other (with the proper offsets) where is the stack the thickest?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Convert your list of ranges to a list of start and stop points. Sort the list with an O(n log n) algorithm. Now you can iterate through the list and increment or decrement a counter depending on whether it's a start or stop point, which will give you the current overlap depth.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be faster IMO. You first have to convert to a list O(N), sort O(N log N), then find the mode O(N).

Comment: @Moop When you combine all of those operations it's O(N log N), which is less than O(N^2).  Now, for small data sets, it's possible it's slower, but it does have a lower asymptotic complexity.

Comment: How would you distinguished if a `int` is a stop or start point?

Comment: Keep a field which indicates this.  It could be a boolean, or perhaps another integer whose value is either `+1` or `-1`, so you can add it to your depth value in either case.

Comment: @Moop, if you're space constrained and with the integer values you specify in your question edit, you could multiply the start/stop values by 2 and add 1 to one or the other. This would be a last resort though, I'd use one of comingstorm's suggestions instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am going to keep this question open for a bit before I select an answer.

Comment: The upshot is that problems of this type are solved by converting them into sorting problems, and there will be no faster algorithm than nlogn unless additional relationships exist in the data.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood OP's question, the solution given the 3 ranges

```
A: 012
B:  123
C:    34
```

would be the range `12` (a common subset of A and B), ***not*** range `123` (because it isn't a common subset of any pair).

---

Think about the algorithm on paper before writing any code. How about a dynamic programming solution? (If you don't know dynamic programming, it's worth reading about it in a book). The idea of dynamic programming is to build up solutions of simpler subproblems.

Let `f_i(n, k)` be the size of the longest interval starting at n common to at least k of the first i given ranges.

You can work out f_1 from f_0, and f_2 from f_1 and so on. Updating the functions just depends on the one extra range considered.

Suppose there are M ranges. The values of f_M will tell us the answer to your problem.

The deepest depth you talked about is the greatest k such that f_M(n, k) is non zero for some n. Let's call that maximal depth K. Then we look for the maximum of f_M(n, K) over n. Its maximum is the size of your largest range, which begins  at the maximising n.

The maximising n must be the lower bound of some range, so we only need to calculate f for these kind of n. There are M ranges, so at most M lower bounds. Thus, this algorithm has complexity O(MMK).

> Let the ith range be from a to b
>
> If n is outside a to b, then no change
>     `f_i(n,k) = f_i-1(n,k)`
>
> If n is within a to b, we test the k deep solution made by combining fresh the interval with our old k-1 deep solution. We only use it if it's better than what we already had. 
>   `f_i(n,k) = max ( f_i-1(n,k) , min( f_i-1(n,k-1) , b-n+1))`

---

Example! For ranges 0 to 5, 2 to 6, 4 to 8, and 6 to 9.

```
n           0123456789

            ......          range 0 to 5
f_1(n,1)    6543210000

              .....         range 2 to 6
f_2(n,1)    6554321000
f_2(n,2)    0043210000

                .....       range 4 to 8
f_3(n,1)    6554543210  
f_3(n,2)    0043321000
f_3(n,3)    0000210000

                  ....      range 6 to 9
f_4(n,1)    6554544321
f_4(n,2)    0043323210
f_4(n,3)    0000211000
f_4(n,4)    0000000000
```

Thus the deepest depth K is 3, and the longest range is 4 to 5. We can also see that the longest range depth 2 has size 4 and starts at 3.

Comment: In this case, the answer would be 123, **not** 12. 123 is continuous, and has the largest mode/depth of 2.

Comment: Then the problem is much simpler and you just need to count. Mark explains the fastest way to do that.